# Does it make sense to merge the tag "financial-education" and "financial-literacy"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Does it make sense to merge the tags [financial-education](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/financial-education) and [financial-literacy](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/financial-literacy)

Edit: Please vote the options so that we can decide which tag to keep

Comment: I think it does; the question is, which do we prefer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we were to merge those, I prefer [financial-literacy](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/financial-literacy).

Comment: Would you merge these tags. Seems like this is preffered one.

Comment: @Dheer Thanks - it's been completed.

Answer (score 1):

The other option is to use [financial-education](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/financial-education)

Answer (score 0):

I think the meanings are different, as literacy is the end result of education. But, unless I am not looking correctly, no questions have either tag, so this discussion my be moot.

Edit - I'll look more to see what post have those tags, not sure what went wrong. 
I get to https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/financial-education which doesn't show any posts.

Edit - Now that I see the questions, I agree, the distinction is too subtle, these two tags should be merged. I'll put my vote in for  [financial-literacy](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/financial-literacy).

Comment: The tags wouldn't exist if there where no questions with those tags.  Click on the tags in the bod of the question or the other two answers and you'll see a list of questions with those tags.  (There are currently 6 for each tag, with one question having both tags.)

Comment: I do agree with your point.  However, that distinction may be too subtle for tags.

Comment: I see 21 questions when I click that link you posted in your answer above.

Comment: Thanks. Now a full page with the 21 shows up. Last two days it showed nothing. I was going to look at the questions and tags used to see if there was a meaningful difference before commenting further.